# Input String is not correct format when trying to type in a hyphen first

Tags: c#, regex, winforms

I am trying to put a negative number in a textbox, however whenever i click on the textbox and try to type for they hyphen it creates the error, also I don't want it to create this same error if i accidentally leave the textbox blank. as it has done before

```
TextBox tbox = this.Controls.Find("Team" + r.ToString() + "Q" + c.ToString(), true).FirstOrDefault() as TextBox;
int t1 = Convert.ToInt32(tbox.Text);
if (r == 1) team1score += t1;`
```

Comment: At which line it throws the exception?

Comment: I don't know. I just know if i try to type a "-" in the textbox first the error shows up, probably because 'CalculateTotals()' adds up all the textboxes for the team and it comes to the "-" and its not an int

Comment: Please shorten your code down to the throwing exception piece.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's probably because when you type `-`, the `CalculateTotals` method is called and it tries to convert `-` to an integer, and fails. You don't show how you're doing the conversion, which is the most important part of your code. You probably should do something like this:

```
int myInt;
if (!int.TryParse(senderTB.Text, out myInt))
{
    // The value in the textbox isn't an integer.
    // Use 0 as the default.
    myInt = 0;
}
```

That's not entirely correct, though, because the user might type something like `4000000000`, which is larger than an `int`.

A quick fix would be to modify your regular expression so that it requires at least one number:

```
Regex reg = new Regex(@"^-?[0-9]+$");
```

Replacing the `*` with a `+` won't allow just a hyphen to match. This will fix your immediate problem, but it's not complete error checking. But it might be good enough for your purposes.

In general, you can easily use regular expressions to validate the *form* of a signed integer (i.e. an optional hyphen followed by one or more digits), but it's very difficult to use regular expressions to make sure the number is within the range of a signed integer. Making sure that the number is not less than -2147483648 or greater than 2147483647 is rather difficult to do with regular expressions.

You probably want a combination of the approaches: use the regular expression to prevent the user from typing illegal characters into the text box, and use [`int.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Int32.TryParse(v=vs.110).aspx) to validate the number in your `computeTotals` method. And rather than defaulting to a value of 0, have the program display a message box informing the user of the error.

Comment: all i am doing is converting the the Text from the textboxes and adding it to the score. `TextBox tbox = this.Controls.Find("Team" + r.ToString() + "Q" + c.ToString(), true).FirstOrDefault() as TextBox;
                    int t1 = Convert.ToInt32(tbox.Text);
                    if (r == 1) team1score += t1`

Comment: I fixed the Error on the hyphen first by add a parse after the check and in and before calculating total

     `if (!textChangedByKey)
            {
                if (!reg.IsMatch(senderTB.Text))
                {
                    return;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                textChangedByKey = false;
                lastText = senderTB.Text;
                int n = 0;
                if (int.TryParse(senderTB.Text.Trim(), out n))
                {
                    CalculateTotals();
                }`